# Django Rest Framework API Testing with Token authentication and IsAdmin permission Returning 403, AssertionError

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, django-rest-framework, django-testing

good people, I am writing test cases for my django rest framework API for the first time. I have used token authentication and is admin permission. I have written some api endpoint tests. The tests run fine without authentication. I have also done this in POSTMAN and with providing token authorization at headers it runs fine there. But whenever I am running the unit test cases with token authentication and is admin permission it is returning me 403, assertion error. I am stuck with this for the last two days. Can anyone please help me to figure out where I am doing wrong?

I am providing my code below:
My Model:

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='myuser')
    vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vendor_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Vendor_Type)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vendor_mail = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    vendor_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    vendor_address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.display_name
```

My serializer:

```
class VendorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    address_details = VendorAddressDetailSerializer(read_only=True, source='detaisaddress')
    sales_person = VendorContactSerializer(read_only=True, source='contactperson')
    social_account = VendorSocialSerializer(read_only=True, source='vendorsocial')
    class Meta:
        model = Vendor
        fields = ['id','vendor_name', 'vendor_type', 'display_name', 'vendor_mail', 'vendor_phone','vendor_address', 'user', 'address_details', 'sales_person', 'social_account']
```

My view:

```
class VendorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Vendor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VendorSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
```

URL Patterns:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('vendors', VendorViewSet, basename='vendors')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

And Finally my test case code is:

```
class TestSetUp(APITestCase):
    email = "zzm@abcd.com"
    phone = "0122xxxxxxx"
    name = "zzm"
    address = "zzmkk"
    password = "1234xxxx"

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = MyUser.objects.create_user(self.email, self.phone, self.name, self.address, self.password)
        self.user.is_admin = True
        self.user.save()
        self.token = Token.objects.get(user=self.user)

        self.vendor_url = reverse('vendors-list')


    self.my_dummy_user = {
            "email": "temp@gmail.com",
            "phone": "01222xxx",
            "name": "temp",
            "address": "tempxx",
            "password": "1234xxxxx",
        }


    def _create_my_user(self):
        my_user = MyUser.objects.create_user(
            **self.my_dummy_user,
        )
        my_user.is_admin = True
        my_user.is_superuser = True
        my_user.save()
        return {
            "my_user": my_user,
        }

    def test_vendor_post_201(self):
        data = self._create_my_user()
        token = Token.objects.get(user__name= data.get('my_user').name)
        vendor_data = {
            "vendor_name": "lama",
            "vendor_type": "person",
            "display_name": "lama co",
            "vendor_mail": "lama@gmail.com",
            "vendor_phone": "0133xxxxx",
            "vendor_address": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "user": data.get('my_user').id
        }
        client = APIClient()
        client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
        # headers = {'Authorization': 'token ' + token.key}
        res = client.post(self.vendor_url, vendor_data, format="json")
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 201)
        return res.data
```

Advance thanks to the good souls. It would be a great help for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you who have encountered and tried to answer my question. But I have figured it out I was using InAdmin permission, So, users with admin permission can do the post, In django to give user the admin permission, has to do this: `is_stuff=True` not `is_admin=True`. so my default user function should look like this:

```
def _create_my_user(self):
        my_user = MyUser.objects.create_user(
            **self.my_dummy_user,
        )
        my_user.is_stuff = True
        my_user.save()
        return {
            "my_user": my_user,
        }
```